# Is there a way for an ECS Task to retrieve ec2 metadata of where it(the task) is deployed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

Is there a way for an ECS Task to be able to fetch the EC2 metadata of where it is deployed?

From [AWS documentation of ec2 instance metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html#instancedata-data-retrieval), I can retrieve the EC2 instance metada when I am inside the ec2 instance itself. I'm more interested in fetching the **instance-id** and can be achieved with command

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id
```

This is achieved only when I will go directly to the ec2 instance and execute the query/command, but how will this be possible if I want to  fetch the ec2 metadata when I'm from an ECS task running on the EC2 instance? Based on [AWS documentation of task metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-metadata-endpoint-v2.html), I only managed to fetch the details of the ECS task itself but can't manage to fetch the ec2 metadata where the task is running.

Is this possible?

**The setup:**

- ec2 instance is in an ecs cluster
- ecs task is deployed randomly on any ec2 instance inside the cluster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The metadata endpoint with IP **`169.254.169.254`** is meant for retrieving EC2 details only.

Where as **`169.254.170.2`** is meant for retrieving ECS Task Metadata.

You still should be able to call EC2 Metadata endpoint within task and get EC2 details.

In below sample setup, I had one EC2 instance part of ECS cluster with one `nginx` task running on it.

I ssh'ed (`docker exec -it ab8 /bin/sh`) into my `nginx` task and still able to reach EC2 metadata endpoint properly and got EC2 instanceId(`i-0086xxxxxxxxxxx`).

Now, depending upon your task runtime(java, nodejs, python etc.,), you should be able to make EC2 Metadata call within task.

```
[root@ip-172-31-91-251 ec2-user]# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                             COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                NAMES
ab825479c673        ewoutp/docker-nginx-curl:latest   "nginx"             11 minutes ago      Up 11 minutes       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp   ecs-nginx-17-nginx-c6d8ba82f0afc3f96b00
c99dede7f091        amazon/amazon-ecs-agent:latest    "/agent"            11 days ago         Up 11 days                               ecs-agent

[root@ip-172-31-91-251 ec2-user]# docker exec -it ab8 /bin/sh

# curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id -v
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 169.254.169.254...
* Connected to 169.254.169.254 (169.254.169.254) port 80 (#0)
> GET /latest/meta-data/instance-id HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
> Host: 169.254.169.254
> Accept: */*
> 
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< ETag: "916097910"
< Last-Modified: Tue, 30 Apr 2019 01:59:51 GMT
< Content-Length: 19
< Connection: close
< Date: Tue, 30 Apr 2019 02:07:38 GMT
< Server: EC2ws
< 
* Closing connection 0
i-0086xxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: The EC2 metadata endpoint from within the task container is not accessible, but it is from the instance...on my setup

Comment: you probably have an iptables rule blocking access to it